# Validate password with regex-python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

1. the password must begin with a latin letter,
2. the password can consist of Latin letters, numbers, dot and minuses,
3. the password must end only with a latin letter or number;
4. minimum password length is one character
5. maximum password length is 20 characters

'''

```
def passwd_check(password):
    LatinList=['','','','','','','','', '','','', '','','', '','','', '','','', '','','', '','','','']
    SpecialChar = ['.','-']
    DigitList = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

    length = len(password)
    if length < 1:
        return False
    

    if length > 20:
        return False
    

    if password[-1] not in LatinList and password[-1] not in DigitList:
        return False
    

    if password[0] not in LatinList:
        return False

    for i in password:
         if i not in LatinList and i not in DigitList and i not in SpecialChar:
            return False
    return True
        
''''
```

anyway to use regex library to fetch latin and satisy the conditon

Answer (score -1):

Those are not Latin letters.  That's the Etruscan alphabet.  Latin letters are the A-Z and a-z you used to write this post.  This should work:

```
re.fullmatch( "^[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9.-]{0-18}[A-Za-z0-9])?$", password )
```